# Compounding Property Names in Spring xml Config file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm sure I likely have more errors than what I'm getting up front, which is a `NullValueInNestedPathException invalid property CompoundProperty1 of bean class CompoundPropertyNamesDemo value of nested property CompoundProperty1 is null`, and I can't seem to get passed it. I'm following the Spring core documentation to implement this feature, but it doesn't really provide me enough information to know what I could be doing wrong. I've never used this technique before and don't understand how it should be implemented

```
<!-- xml config file -->

<bean id="compoundPropertyNamesDemo"
  class="com.spring.introduction.xml_config.compond.property.names.CompoundPropertyNamesDemo">
    <property name="compoundProperty1.compoundProperty2.compoundProperty3" 
        ref="compoundProperty3"/>   
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="compoundProperty1"
    class="com.spring.introduction.xml_config.compond.property.names.CompoundProperty1">
    <constructor-arg name="cp2" ref="compoundProperty2" />
    <constructor-arg name="strcp1" value="message in cp1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="compoundProperty2"
    class="com.spring.introduction.xml_config.compond.property.names.CompoundProperty2">
    <constructor-arg name="cp3" ref="compoundProperty3" />
    <constructor-arg name="strcp2" value="message in cp2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="compoundProperty3"
    class="com.spring.introduction.xml_config.compond.property.names.CompoundProperty3">
    <property name="message"
        value="result of properties chained together in one bean" />
</bean>
```

Simple Java classes must not be null when included in the Compound Property chain except for the last property in the chain. It can be of a null value.

```
/** Pojos */

public class CompoundPropertyNamesDemo {
    
    private CompoundProperty1 compoundProperty1;

    public CompoundProperty1 getCompoundProperty1() {
        return compoundProperty1;
    }

    public void setCompoundProperty1(CompoundProperty1 compoundProperty1) {
        this.compoundProperty1 = compoundProperty1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompoundPropertyNamesDemo [compoundProperty1=" + compoundProperty1 + "]";
    }
    
}
```

must not be null in the Compound Property chain in the xml configs

```
public class CompoundProperty1 {

    private CompoundProperty2 cp2;
    private String strcp1;
    
    public CompoundProperty1(CompoundProperty2 cp2, String strcp1) {
        this.cp2 = cp2;
        this.strcp1 = strcp1;
    }

    public CompoundProperty2 getCp2() {
        return cp2;
    }

    public void setCp2(CompoundProperty2 cp2) {
        this.cp2 = cp2;
    }

    public String getStrcp1() {
        return strcp1;
    }

    public void setStrcp1(String strcp1) {
        this.strcp1 = strcp1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompoundProperty1 [cp2=" + cp2 + ", strcp1=" + strcp1 + "]";
    }
    
}
```

must not be null in the Compound Property chain in the xml configs

```
public class CompoundProperty2 {

    private CompoundProperty3 cp3;
    private String strcp2;
    
    public CompoundProperty2(CompoundProperty3 cp3, String strcp2) {
        this.cp3 = cp3;
        this.strcp2 = strcp2;
    }

    public CompoundProperty3 getCp3() {
        return cp3;
    }

    public void setCp3(CompoundProperty3 cp3) {
        this.cp3 = cp3;
    }

    public String getStrcp2() {
        return strcp2;
    }

    public void setStrcp2(String strcp2) {
        this.strcp2 = strcp2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompoundProperty2 [cp3=" + cp3 + ", strcp2=" + strcp2 + "]";
    }

}
```

represent the last property in the Compound Property chain in the xml configs

```
public class CompoundProperty3 {
    
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CompondProperty3 [message=" + message + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize until after I posted, I forgot to remove the irrelevant closing tag for the </property> element in the first bean definitions. Please overlook this mistake.

Comment: I've found that if I use the abstract="true" attribute in the 1st bean, the one doing the compound property chaining, the code compiles and runs, only I am unable to assign a value to the last property. I changed the xml and attempted to assign a value to the message attribute, after adding it to the chain, and was still getting a null value.